# Approved Orders Not Showing Up in PayPal Transaction History

Tags: php, paypal

I am using the [PayPal API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/) to process payments on my website (it is hosted locally for now).

I create the order with `CAPTURE` as the intent and once the payment is successfully submitted I get back an `APPROVED` response. However, the balance on my PayPal account has not been updated nor have the orders been added to my PayPal transaction history (even after days). I am using my LIVE credentials and not the sandbox so that shouldn't be an issue.

I found someone on the PayPal forums with the [exact same problem](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/REST-APIs/Approved-Orders-Not-Showing-Up-in-Transaction-History/td-p/2654381) but no response.

Here is my backend code that checks if the order submitted on the client has been approved:

```
$orderId = $_POST['orderId'];
$url = "https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/$orderId";

$headers = array(
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($clientId . ':' . $clientSecret),
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($response) {
  $responseData = json_decode($response, true);
  $orderStatus = $responseData['status'];
  
  if ($orderStatus === 'APPROVED') {
      // this part runs but my PayPal balance does not change
      echo 'SUCCESS';
  }
}
```

Comment: Once the order is approved by the buyer, you need to [capture the order](https://api-m.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/{id}/capture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For complete steps, see the [standard integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/).

After an order is approved it must be captured. The capture request may succeed or fail. You should display a success or failure message to the payer based on this response.

Use the JS SDK for approval and do this from the `onApprove` function.